# Facebook periodic review is unclear

Tags: facebook, hello.js

```
in order to approve your app’s continued operation on our platform.
Platforms affected: Connect URL.
Developer Policy 1.2: Build an app that is stable and easily navigable.Some common violations of this policy include:
 - Broken Facebook integration (e.g. broken share, like or comment functionality)
 - Broken user experience in the app (e.g. app has broken links or user interface failures)
```

My app:

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/hellojs v1.18.8 to query user info from facebook.

The request URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,name,timezone,verified&access_token=.....

calling out hello.js

```
hello(auth.network).api('me').then(function (json) {
```

App has no share, like, comment functionality and not really any user interface. Just our page offers ability to fill some data with facebook and then it remembers you with cookie.

Anyone has similar e-mail and what to do?

Our app does not use share, like or comment functionality neither do we provide any user interface for users (only the o. We are using Facebook to prefill some user data on our site.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same unclear message "Platform affected: Connect Url".
I asked for a more detailed answer and received an answer the next day:

> Thank you for your response.
>
> Facebook periodically reviews the websites and applications which are on it. Your application is in its review process currently. We are required to test the Facebook login functionality in order to conclude the review in totality. However, we are unable to do so.
>
> Unfortunately, we have not been able to locate a Facebook integration (Login, Share and Like) on your submitted platform. To help us conclude the review process, could you kindly share the details regarding the location of a Facebook integration and how to navigate to it on your website URL.
>
> This review is essential to Facebook as we want to offer the best experience to users as well as developers like yourself. Please help us in bringing your application into compliance by working with us.
>
> Alternatively, you could aid us by sending us credentials of a test user which is already registered and connected to an FB account within the app. You can get all the information related to creating a test user here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users.
>
> Please feel free to get in touch with us regarding any doubts or queries you might have.
>
> Thank you for your patience and cooperation.
>
> Looking forward to hearing from you.

My app contains the functionality of a facebook login. I made an instruction and a test user of the application so that Facebook employees could test the functionality used in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Normally they write down what is wrong and explain how to fix it. If you are not sure you can reply them back and ask how to fix it. I manage to fix my issue which was similar to the one explain below by emailing facebook.

https://technuisance.com/facebook/facebook-policy-warning-for-app-solved.html

Answer (score -1):

I got the same message from Facebook two months ago. In my case, I didn't find a solution in time and Facebook penalize me by deactivating the app.

Therefore, you must attend to it if you do not want the same to happen to you. Facebook uses software similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) to check for failures on your site and assigns a score according to its performance. That's why they send you such a generic message.

I suggest you use [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) to receive a report on the performance of your website. In addition, the platform gives you suggestions for optimization and improvement; Surely there you will find some clue of what may be failing.